# How to create an vector with incremental values based on values of another vector?

Tags: r

I have a vector v1 and using it, I want to create another vector v2
Here, `v1 = c(7,6,5)`, `v2 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5)`

I want to get `v2` with and without loops, both. How is it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sequence` to generate the numbers.

```
sequence(v1)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4 5
```

And with a loop using `lapply`:

```
unlist(lapply(v1, seq))
```